# Windows Vista taskbar flashing[FIXED]

Tags: windows-vista, taskbar

I am having an issue with my Taskbar in Windows Vista. Sometimes the top of it blinks blue and sometimes it completely flashes. It happens about every 2 seconds and it gets worse as I go on without a Reboot. I have tried system restoring before the issue happened but it still didn't work.

EDIT : I actually left my computer on for 6 hours and now it works!

Comment: Do you have Norton Internet Security or Norton 360 installed? Seen similar to this before and it turned out to be something gone wrong with Norton... Use the Norton removal tool to completely remove, rather than simply "uninstalling"... report back :)

Comment: Thank you Chris! I fixed it somehow by leaving it on for 6 Hours :D (also I did not have Norton, #AVGFTW :D)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to have been a hiccup that is no longer reproducible.